# Liferay- landing to different communities based on their user-groups

Tags: redirect, liferay

My requirement is that i have a liferay portal which has two types of user creation process:

1. Manual creation by the admin
2. Users can create via create account

I want to land the users to different landing pages based on the user-groups. User creation process1 belongs to one group and process2 belongs to another group. How to achieve it. Process1 is working fine by setting the default landing path but i want to land the users who are created by process2 to a different landing page.

Thanks in advance!!

Regards,
S.Ponraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the page [here](http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/07/custom-landing-page-using-hook-liferay.html) for information on how to create a landing page hook.

You will also need a way to identify if the user is from process 1 or process 2. One possible approach would be using liferay custom fields (expando).

Comment: Thanks Alain for your reply. The link you gave is for liferay 6.1 but i am using 5.2.3 whether the procedure is same for 5.2.3 or it varies

Comment: Take a look at [http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing+the+default+page+after+login](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing+the+default+page+after+login) for info on previous versions of liferay

Comment: hey thanks again Alain. i was able to create a custom field in order to identify the user belonging to which process. but how to retrieve the value of custom field.

Comment: I assume you added the custom variable to the user. You can extract it with user.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("attributeName"); See also the liferay wiki [Developing with Expando](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+with+Expando)

Comment: oh yes i am working on it hope it ends up with a good result thanks Alain :)